# I want to develop human emotion recognition application by analyzing voice features,how do I start this?I don't have idea.

Tags: svm, libsvm, praat

I want to develop human emotion recognition application by analyzing voice features,how do I start this?I don't have idea.

http://www.personal.rdg.ac.uk/~llsroach/phon2/freespeech.htm
http://web.stanford.edu/dept/linguistics/corpora/material/PRAAT_workshop_manual_v421.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to look at the available literature first:

http://www.pyoudeyer.com/emotionsIJHCS.pdf

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.467.7166&rep=rep1&type=pdf

http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Theodoros_Iliou/publication/267698141_Classification_on_Speech_Emotion_Recognition_-_A_Comparative_Study/links/5519be060cf244e9a4584c07.pdf

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6531196

Comment: OK, Thankyou so much  :) I did a literature survey, I want to create and train a model.but I want to get to know how to start these things,because I am new to these things.

Comment: can you please help me to start my research

Comment: @Hasfa001: Sorry, but this question is way too broad. What do you expect me to do, write the code for you? Read the literature, understand the methods they use, and implement one of them. This *will* take work, there is no way around it.

Comment: not at all.I want to train a model.can you please tell me how to implement a model with sample audio file.I have a sample voice database which has 200+ audio files.I think you know about machine learning also